# Android app doesn't appear like the preview

Tags: android, xml, android-studio, android-layout

My app interface is supposed to be like the below preview

[image]

But it appears to be like this instead

[image]

As you can see, there's a gap between the search bar and the top of the screen when I run the app. What's causing this problem ? and How can I fix this ?

I tried to set the `margin_top` to `0dp` but no use.

My xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".ui.dashboard.DashboardFragment">

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:id="@+id/tag_spinner_constraint"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

        <SearchView
            android:id="@+id/search_bar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="45dp"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@id/tag_spinner_constraint"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@id/tag_spinner_constraint"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@id/tag_spinner_constraint" />

        <HorizontalScrollView
            android:id="@+id/filter_bar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:scrollbars="none"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/search_bar">

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="horizontal">

                <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatButton
                    android:id="@+id/empty_rooms_btn"
                    android:layout_width="99dp"
                    android:layout_height="34dp"
                    android:layout_marginStart="5dp"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
                    android:background="@drawable/rounded_button"
                    android:text="Phòng trống"
                    android:textSize="12sp"
                    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/floor_spinner" />

                <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatButton
                    android:id="@+id/not_full_rooms_btn"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="34dp"
                    android:layout_marginStart="12dp"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="12dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
                    android:background="@drawable/rounded_button"
                    android:text="Phòng ghép"
                    android:textSize="12sp"
                    app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/empty_rooms_btn"
                    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/floor_spinner" />

                <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatButton
                    android:id="@+id/full_rooms_btn"
                    android:layout_width="105dp"
                    android:layout_height="34dp"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
                    android:background="@drawable/rounded_button"
                    android:text="Phòng đã đầy"
                    android:textSize="12sp"
                    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
                    app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/not_full_rooms_btn"
                    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/floor_spinner" />

                <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatButton
                    android:id="@+id/all_rooms_btn"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="34dp"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
                    android:background="@drawable/rounded_button"
                    android:text="Tất cả"
                    android:textSize="12sp" />

            </LinearLayout>

        </HorizontalScrollView>

    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>


    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/contract_list"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/tag_spinner_constraint"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="1.0">


    </ListView>

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you everyone for your help !
I've already tried the two above solutions and realized that the problem is not in the fragment xml file but in the `activity_main.xml` file

activity_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingTop="?attr/actionBarSize">

    <com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView
        android:id="@+id/nav_view"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="0dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="0dp"
        android:background="?android:attr/windowBackground"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:menu="@menu/bottom_nav_menu" />

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/nav_host_fragment"
        android:name="androidx.navigation.fragment.NavHostFragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:defaultNavHost="true"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/nav_view"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:navGraph="@navigation/mobile_navigation" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

focus on the `android:paddingTop="?attr/actionBarSize"` line inside the parent most constraint layout configuration. That's causing the problem, just get rid of it and I am good to go.

Answer (score 1):

All you need is the [layout inspector](https://developer.android.com/studio/debug/layout-inspector). It is an embedded utility that can help to figure out which UI widget adds an unneeded gap.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, you should create a new style with parents as NoActionBar to remove the App bar from the activity.

```
<style name="Theme.AppName" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.DayNight.NoActionBar">
.
. 
</style>
```

Secondly, you have to add that NoActionBar theme to the activity in theme attribute in the manifest.

```
<activity 
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.Design.Light.NoActionBar">
```

Lastly, you have to add an AppBar attribute to the XML inside the constraint layout with searchView inside that.

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
. 
. >

<com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/appBarLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="@android:color/white"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

        <SearchView
            android:id="@+id/search_bar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" />

</com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout>

.
.
.
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```